# How to differentiate $(x!)\uparrow\uparrow(!x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, factorial, tetration

I need help in differentiating the following expression with respect to x, which I recently came up with when trying to differentiate expressions involving subfactorials...

$$(x!)\uparrow\uparrow(!x)$$

[Here, x $\in$ $\Bbb C$]

I would appreciate it, if the answerer could elaborate the method used to solve this problem; even a constructive hint would be excellent.

Note: Tetration, here, is quintessentially the next hyper operator after exponentiation. More details -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: For what values of $x$ is your expression defined? Usually factorials are defined only for non-negative integers.

Comment: I have never seen the up-arrow notation for non-natural input. Differentiating over the integers is not very well defined, apart from polynomials, and this is not a polynomial.

Comment: I suppose some attempts have been made at extending the up-arrow notation to non-naturals, but even the simpler case of tetration doesn't have an extension that is widely agreed on. In short: You have to specify in detail what this notation means if anybody should have a chance of helping you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that x belongs to the set $Z^+$ 
(a.k.a Positive Integers). @HowDoIMath I've mentioned the values of x for which x is defined. Also, factorials can be extended to complex numbers as well using the Gamma function extension.

Comment: @Kugelblitz: Differentation over the positive integers is not very well defined, so you also have to specify what you mean by that. (And extending the factorial to $\mathbb C$ is the easy part of making your question well defined.)

Comment: I initially thought it might be easier for people to do so over the set of positive integers. In fact, I initially wished to define x to be part of ℂ. I guess I'll edit it then...

Comment: Then we're back to the notation not being defined in any widely agreed on way for the domain.

Comment: @Henrik You're right about the notation's usage not being widely agreed upon... But the most common way, I think, it's defined over complex numbers, is http://www.tetration.org/Tetration/

Comment: @williewong, Since you've edited my question, could you provide an answer?

Comment: @Kugelblitz: Willie added a *tag* to your question... And even if they had edited it more, it does not mean at all that they would be able to answer.

Comment: The subfactorial has a representation using the incomplete Gamma function, and according to the website you yourself linked to two comments above there are formulae for derivatives for the other operator. Why not just put them together yourself and see what you get?

Comment: @JeanHominal Oh no! You got me wrong! I didn;t mean that in a rude way at all! :) I just thought that he could answer the question because from other posts of it he looked quite intelligent. :

Comment: I tried but I wasn't successful; recently I was trying to prove some simpler cases of this question, so if I can solve those, I can maybe solve this one.. @WillieWong

Comment: Your is a hard objective, of course you can extend factorials from naturals to almost all reals with the Gamma function but then you'll have the problem to define tetration for arbitrary argument and then you'll have a very messy expression to differentiate. Good luck! (+1)

Comment: @Kugelblitz: This paper is related to your question  http://vixra.org/abs/1305.0040